# How can update my session using ajax?

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

I'm using a session for setting language

```
if(!isset($GLOBALS['lang'])){
    $GLOBALS['lang'] = 'en';
}
```

Then I'm using `ajax` to update this:

```
var lang = 'no'; 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
          lang : lang
    },
    success: function (data) { (...) }
});
```

The file being called looks like this:

```
global $lang;

if(strlen($_POST['lang']) == 2 ){
    $lang = $_POST['lang'];
    $result = array('lang_set' => $lang);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

But my global session is not changed. I'm guessing this is due to the fact that `lang.php` uses another session instance.

I'm using Wordpress so I'm looking into if I can use some of the built in functions for this purpose. But I'm wondering if I can use PHP sessions for keeping track of selected language? Or do I have to use another method like adding selected language to my url?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Ghost, I made it work. If you are using Wordpress, I'm doing the following in `functions.php`:

```
// Initialize session
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}

// Set lang session with default language
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'no';
}

//globals
$GLOBALS['lang'] = $_SESSION['lang'];
```

Comment: `if( !session_id() ){session_start();}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them to persist on the entire application, use sessions:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}
```

Then on the other:

```
session_start();

if(strlen($_POST['lang']) == 2 ){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['lang'];
    $result = array('lang_set' => $_SESSION['lang']);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: That will not work (tested) because when you open lang.php, it creates another session instance (I think).

Comment: @Steven nope, it will work, you need a session_start() on those scripts where you need to access session variables

Comment: Yea, sorry - my bad. I forgot `session_start();`in my lang.php file. Thanks :)

Comment: @Steven anyway, the important thing is its always on top of your php file, and don't call it twice in the same php file.

Comment: I only call it twice. Once in `lang.php` and once in my `function.php` file - where I place the session in `$GLOBALS['lang']`

Comment: @Steven yes thats what i mean by that, one invocation for each files